# Python - Open All Text Files in All Subdirectories Unless Text File Is In Specified Directory

Tags: python, path, operating-system, filepath, subdirectory

I have a directory (named "Top") that contains ten subdirectories (named "1", "2", ... "10"), and each of those subdirectories contains a large number of text files. I would like to be able to open all of the files in subdirectories 2-10 without opening the files in the subdirectory 1. (Then I will open files in subdirectories 1 and 3-10 without opening the files in the subdirectory 2, and so forth). Right now, I am attempting to read the files in subdirectories 2-10 without reading the files in subdirectory 1 by using the following code:

```
import os, fnmatch

def findfiles (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join(root, file)

for textfile in findfiles(r'C:\\Top', '*.txt'):
    if textfile in findfiles(r'C:\\Top\\1', '*.txt'):
        pass   
    else:
        filename = os.path.basename(textfile)
        print filename
```

The trouble is, the if statement here ("if textfile in findfiles [...]") does not allow me to exclude the files in subdirectory 1 from the textfile list. Do any of you happen to know how I might modify my code so as to only print the filenames of those files in subdirectories 2-10? I would be most grateful for any advice you can lend on this question.

EDIT:

In case others might find it helpful, I wanted to post the code I ultimately ended up using to solve this problem:

```
import os, fnmatch, glob

for file in glob.glob('C:\\Text\\Digital Humanities\\Packages and Tools\\Stanford Packages\\training-the-ner-tagger\\fixed\*\*'):
    if not file.startswith('C:\\Text\\Digital Humanities\\Packages and Tools\\Stanford Packages\\training-the-ner-tagger\\fixed\\1\\'):
        print file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```
for textfile in findfiles(r'C:\\Top', '*.txt'):
    if not textfile.startswith(r'C:\\Top\\1'):
        filename = os.path.basename(textfile)
        print filename
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, @Brent. For some reason, changing the loop still does not allow me to disregard the files in subdirectory 1. In case it's important, the directory "Top" is buried deep within my file system, so my path actually looks like: C:\\Directory\\Half a Dozen More Directories\\Top\\1 -- should that affect the startswith() method?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the startswith() parameter then.  It should be the exact string (prefix) that you want to exclude from your loop.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I changed the startswith() parameter to match the full path to subdirectory 1, but when I run the loop it still prints filenames that only appear in subdirectory 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you include the `not` in `if not textfile.startswith(...)`?

Comment: Yes. For some reason I'm still seeing filenames from subdirectory 1. I'm working in Python 2.7, Windows 8...

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the strings.  You're using `r''` strings with double backslashes.  Change the line to use `startswith('path')` (without the "r").

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35954/discussion-between-brent-washburne-and-dduhaime)

Comment: Still no luck, though I am most grateful for your suggestion!

Comment: @dduhaime  Why don't you try my suggestions?  I tested them and they worked!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as simple as that you are using extra `\`s in your constants.  Write instead:

```
for textfile in findfiles(r'C:\Top', '*.txt'):
    if textfile in findfiles(r'C:\Top\1', '*.txt'):
        pass   
    else:
        filename = os.path.basename(textfile)
        print filename
```

The `\\` would be correct if you hadn't used raw (`r''`) strings.
If the performance of this code is too bad, try:

```
exclude= findfiles(r'C:\Top\1', '*.txt')
for textfile in findfiles(r'C:\Top', '*.txt'):
    if textfile in exclude:
        pass   
    else:
        filename = os.path.basename(textfile)
        print filename
```